# Git checkout in Chef recipe not working

Tags: git, chef-infra, recipe

I used the following chef stanza to try and checkout a github repository:

```
   git "/home/ubuntu" do
     repository "git://github.com/kmerenkov/brukva.git"
     revision "master"
     action :checkout
     user "ubuntu"
   end
```

The chef run has no errors and the resource is shown as up to date (even though no files are in the target directory).

```
* git[/home/ubuntu] action checkout (up to date)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, Im using git 1.8.3 and chef 11.8.0 . I have tried this with multiple github repositories with no luck

Comment: It looks like this is a place where you would use clone, not checkout.  Is the checkout you are using specific to chef?  Does it actually mean clone?

Comment: Unfortunately there are currently only three "actions" for the git resource sync, checkout and export. Checkout is used to clone a source repo - http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
git "/home/ubuntu/brukva" do
  repository "git://github.com/kmerenkov/brukva.git"
  revision "master"
  action :sync
  user "ubuntu"
end
```

It does nothing if your target directory exists when using `:checkout` because it assumes your checkout is done already, you can see chef tells "up to date".

Refer to the [source](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/git.rb#L75) of git provider

Comment: @jhngmsith if this solved your question, could you please mark it as "correct"

Comment: You may omit `action :sync` because it is default action.